# error during saving model - Unexpected token new

Tags: mongoose, model, schema

im getting an error during saving model. Here's what ive got
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBsBL.png)

Comment: Posting screenshots of code and error messages is discouraged. See why:
 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: addded new comment

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you forgot to add `async` before callback function.
If you want to write a code using `async/await` your code must be look like:

```
app.get('/api/article, async (req, res) => { 
  const article = await new Article({
    ....properties...
}).save();
```